# Implementing Text Based Adventure into a GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So has  a group project we have created a Text based adventure game and have to incorporate a GUI into the game. While the GUI and the TBA work fine separate I'm having trouble combining the two. I need the user to enter there command in the Entry Box and depending on there input have the GUI print out the text from the existing functions. I am using tkinter for the GUI. Any help would be much appreciated!

Part of the Text Based Adventure

```
def initWorldVals():
worldVals = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,'Start Room']
global worldVals

## Room class
class Room:
def __init__(self,x,y,name,desc,memo):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc
    self.memo = memo

def getX(self):
    return self.x
def getY(self):
    return self.y
def getName(self):
    return self.name
def getDesc(self):
    return self.desc
def getMemo(self):
    return self.memo
numOfRooms = len(roomList)


for i in range(numOfRooms):
  roomList[i] = Room(rooms[i*3],rooms[(i*3)+1],
                   rooms[(i*3)+2],desc[(i*2)+1],memo[i])

 ## Main program functions
 # Room movement

def actionRoom(x,y,commLine,roomList,actionType):
   if commLine == "NORTH":
    y += 1
    if actionType == 'GO':
        for i in range(numOfRooms):
            if roomList[i].getX() == x and roomList[i].getY() == y:
                worldVals[7] = roomList[i].getName()
                worldVals[6] = roomList[i].getY()
        if worldVals[5] != x or worldVals[6] != y:
            errorComm(commLine,'GO')
    elif actionType == 'LOOK':
        for i in range(numOfRooms):
            if roomList[i].getX() == x and roomList[i].getY() == y:
                print(roomList[i].getMemo())
                lookRoomNum = i
                return lookRoomNum
        if roomList[lookRoomNum] != x or roomList[lookRoomNum] != y:
            errorComm(commLine,'LOOK')

elif commLine == "SOUTH":
    y -= 1
    if actionType == 'GO':
        for i in range(numOfRooms):
            if roomList[i].getX() == x and roomList[i].getY() == y:
                if roomList[i] == roomList[5] and worldVals[1] == 0:
                    print("Without looking, you step into the room "
                          "blindly, and fall into a large pit in the "
                          "center of the room.  The fall is too great, "
                          "and you do not survive the fall.\n\n")
                    worldVals[0] = -1
                worldVals[7] = roomList[i].getName()
                worldVals[6] = roomList[i].getY()
        if worldVals[5] != x or worldVals[6] != y:
            errorComm(commLine,'GO')

    elif actionType == 'LOOK':
        for i in range(numOfRooms):
            if roomList[i].getX() == x and roomList[i].getY() == y:
                if roomList[i] == roomList[5]:
                    worldVals[1] = 1
                print(roomList[i].getMemo())
                lookRoomNum = i
                return lookRoomNum
        if roomList[lookRoomNum] != x or roomList[lookRoomNum] != y:
            errorComm(commLine,'LOOK')
```

GUI Code:

```
from tkinter import *

import sys

class Display(Frame):

  mGui = Tk()
  mGui.geometry("500x500-500-300") #Size of Widget
  mGui.title("Text Based Adventure!")
  mlabel = Label(mGui,text = "Welcome adventurer where do you wish to go").pack()


def __init__(self):
   Frame.__init__(self)
   self.entry = Entry(self) #Entry textbox
   self.entry.pack()
   self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter) 
   self.clearButton = Button(self, text="Clear text", command=self.clear_text) #Clear text button
   self.clearButton.pack() 
   self.output = Text(self) #Textbox
   self.output.pack()
   sys.stdout = self
   self.pack()


def onEnter(self,Frame):

    print(self.entry.get()) #Waits for enter to display text


def write(self, txt):
    self.output.insert(END,str(txt)) #displays text



def clear_text(self):
    self.entry.delete(0, "end") #Clears text

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Display().mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you're getting or problems you're having?

Comment: Im just having problems with adding the text based adventure to the GUI. So basically right now the text based adventure game is displaying the output in idle I want the output to display in the GUI I have created, just don't know the correct way of doing so.

Comment: If you have an input in the gui, then the user can presumably just type into that. So think about how you can grab that text.. you need to access the text value of that box/field.. and for output, again, look for how to access the text value of your output box, and make it equal to the output of your game code.